# reged allow normal and accent letters in Spanish but block special characters and numbers

Tags: regex, string, special-characters

Hi I need to do some validation and make sure that the String does not contain any Special character or numbers. However I am using Spanish language therefore I need the accent letters and also normal letters to be allowed with spaces as well.

```
        String text = "áa @s";
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    if(text.matches(".*\\p{L}.*") && !text.matches(".*\\d+.*"))
        System.out.println("SI");
```

The output here will print "SI" but it should not since it includes "@"
This code exclude numbers and allow accent spanish letters but I want to block special characters and exclude them as well.
Any help will be appreciated.
Note : I am flexible with any method as long as I achieve the goal of having a clean Spanish string with only letters (including accent letters) and spaces. 
Finally if there is away to do all this in one regex that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that `text.matches(".*\\p{L}.*")` only assert that there is *a* letter in your text. It should definitely be possible to assert in one regex that your whole text is composed of standard letters and combining marks, I'm looking into it.

Comment: yes but @ is not a letter in that case but maybe he is matching it because of .* that allows anything. It would be nice if I did something like   if(text.matches("[^\\p{L}\\s]")) so here I think it should work in which I don't allow anything outside of that poundry that is not a letter or space but it is not working

Comment: \\p{L} isn't enough if you want to match accentuated characters, you also need \\p{M}. I was just looking http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html which is a goldmine of informations on regex. There are a few interesting classes, but it looks like you're out of luck with the Java regex engine.

Comment: should I use Pattern instead of matches or the same issue as an engine

Comment: yeah, they both use the same underlying regex engine. Can you try matching on `(\\p{L}\\p{M}*)+` ? I'm really not sure the letter exclude special characters but it's worth trying I guess

Comment: Well, looks like it's working : https://regex101.com/r/vP6lW9/1. I'll add an answer

Comment: ok this works but it is not including spaces      if(text.matches("(\\p{L}\\p{M}*)+")) I tried adding \\s but still it does not work with spaces

Comment: try `(\p{L}\p{M}*\s*)+`

Comment: perfect it works now many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\p{L}` matches an unicode letter (as opposed to any symbol) and is the way to go.
However, you certainly discovered it didn't (always) matched accented letters. That's because in unicode, accented letters can sometimes be represented as two characters : the letter without the accent, followed by a combining mark that represents the accent.
The class to match these one is `\p{M}`, which gives us the following code (considering a comment where you said you wanted to include spaces) :

```
if(text.matches("(?:\\p{L}\\p{M}*\\s*)+")) { System.out.println("Muy bien !"); }
```

More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: Can you tell me why the \\s worked after the * but not before it??? as I tried before

Comment: I don't see where you put the \\s, but you must consider that `\\p{L}\\p{M}*` represents a single letter. If you put a mandatory space in the same group, you'd only match a string where each letter is separated by a space